# Lab test database modeling help

Tags: database-design

I have a database design problem which I need some help with.

I am developing a database to store some engineering lab test results. But the main problem I am running into is that each `Test` is completely different from each other in terms of inputs and results. For example, `Test1` measures `Measurement1` at three different `Frequencies`. `Test2` measures `Measurement2` at five different `Temperatures`.

If I am running multple `Tests` on sample, what is the best way to go about it?

1. I can create independent tables for each `Test` and address this in the interface code.
2. I can have a normalized database with `Test` table and `Results` table. Store the columns required for all the `Tests` in there, eventhough some will be empty for  a particular `Test`.

Any help on this is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of your approaches is good.

You have Tests that produce Results for some Measurement that is done with some Method. The Method may applies to multiple Test. (see sample Data below)

So this is my approach

```
Test(**TestID**, Name, Description, ...)
Measurement(**MeasurementID**, TestID[FK], Description)
Result(**Measurement[FK]**, **ResultNr**, ResultValue, Time)
```

Sample Data:

```
Test
0 | Rat in the Maze | Our rat John in the large Maze testing him find the exit
1 | Water on the oven | Boiling Water on our nuclear oven 

Measurement
0 | 0 | Distance to Exit in cm
0 | 1 | Aggressiveness of the rat in Units of Aggressiveness 
1 | 1 | Temperature of the water in K
2 | 1 | Energy currently consumed by nuclear oven in W
3 | 1 | Amount of water evaporated

Result
0 | 0 | 10 | 0s
0 | 1 | 12 | 2s
0 | 2 | 7  | 6s
...
```

Ok however this still relies on your use case. Maybe you want to keep some other table for input circumstances and map them to your results as a FK.

But note how it differs from your approach:

- Number of tables independet from number of Tests, Results, Mesuret Values
- No Empty rows and expandable for more Measured Values.

You can still add more information (Columns) to the Measurment table to keep track of the Device used to measure, the accuracy or whatever.